# User.findUserByEmail is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

I'm using nodejs and mongoose , using express-validator to validating email duplicate,

```
  check("email")
    .custom(value => {
        return User.findUserByEmail(value).then(user => {
        if (user) {
            return Promise.reject('E-mail already in use');
        }
        });
    })
```

and when posting  with duplicated email i've got error saying

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "value": "boka@gmail.com",
      "msg": "User.findUserByEmail is not a function",
      "param": "email",
      "location": "body"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've used reference as https://express-validator.github.io/docs/custom-validators-sanitizers.html#example-checking-if-e-mail-is-in-use

I tried to use other method such as `findOne`

```
.custom(value => {
        return User.findOne({value}).then(user => {
        if (user) {
            return Promise.reject('E-mail already in use');
        }
        });
    })
```

It does works but , It *return response as  duplicate even if email is not duplicate but writes to db*

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "value": "boka1@gmail.com",
      "msg": "E-mail already in use",
      "param": "email",
      "location": "body"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there something i'm missing thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `mongoose`, there is no such method on models called `findUserByEmail` that's why you are getting that error.

You can use `findOne` instead. If you insist, I think you should define it yourself in your model.

```
User.findUserByEmail = (email) => {
  return this.findOne({ email: email })
  // or return User.findOne({ email: email })
}
```

Comment: :) yes problem solved

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.custom((value, { req }) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                reject(new Error("Server Error"));
            }
            if (Boolean(user)) {
                reject(new Error("E-mail already in use"));
            }
            resolve(true);
        });
    });
}),
```

check this ...